# Expand an array with Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I'm analyzing data with Apache pig and could not find a way to expand an array if items.
Here is the schema I'm working with, and an example of the desired output:

```
(col1:int, col2:int, items:{ARRAY_ELEM:(name:chararray, total:int)})
input  = (1, 1, {("bird", 5), ("bear", 12), ("wolf", 10)})
output = (1, 1, "bird", 5, "bear", 12, "wolf", 10)
```

Is there any way to do this transformation?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do this transformation right now the easiest way is probably to do a **UDF** in Python or Java (I am not aware of any built-in solution).

However, most of the time it is better to keep the **same number of columns** in **each record** (e.g. keep your array as a bag or tuple and don't "flatten" it in one record).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this Python UDF I wrote for doing that](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2529) (hopefully soon to be part of Python PiggyBank). You can use that on your bags and then flatten them to get the results you want, for example, assuming your data set is called blah, you should be able to register my function and then do something like:

```
flattened_blah = FOREACH blah GENERATE item1, item2, FLATTEN(bagToTuple(item3)) AS item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9
```

Also, I'm pretty sure [LinkedIn's DataFu](http://engineering.linkedin.com/open-source/introducing-datafu-open-source-collection-useful-apache-pig-udfs) has a way of doing this. If you're using Pig and not yet using that, you probably should take a look at it.