# Load JSON data containing arrays in PIG

Tags: arrays, json, apache-pig

I have JSON file of the format:

```
{"id": "59b6808364fdb09cde10ad3b","balance": "$1,972.02","age": 35,"eyeColor": "green","tags": ["aute","nostrud","pariatur","adipisicing","irure"]}
{"id": "59b6808334cd60be95e5c166","balance": "$3,697.85","age": 32,"eyeColor": "blue","tags": ["tempor","non","ad","adipisicing","ut"]}
{"id": "59b680834544a828191abc88","balance": "$1,102.43","age": 38,"eyeColor": "brown","tags": ["quis","non","ut","veniam","ipsum"]}
```

I need to load this data into pig. I am using:

```
raw_data = LOAD '/path/to/file' USING JsonLoader('id:chararray, balance:chararray, age:int, eyeColor:chararray, tags:chararray')
```

I am not getting correct result using this when using `dump raw_data;`

What is the correct data type to load arrays in Apache PIG?
There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9522991/7321201) which mentions how to expand an array but for my case I can have variable elements in `tags` element.

Even if I could covert the array to string and then load it that would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the field inside tags with {}

```
raw_data = LOAD '/path/to/file' USING JsonLoader('id:chararray, balance:chararray, age:int, eyeColor:chararray, tags:{items:chararray}')
```

Comment: What worked for me is this: `raw_data = LOAD '/path/to/file' USING JsonLoader('id:chararray, balance:chararray, age:int, eyeColor:chararray, tags:{(items:chararray)}')` **the parenthesis around** `items:chararray`

Comment: my JSON data is however unstructured and JsonLoader works for structured data. Some lines in my JSON file do not have some fields and JsonLoader loads values by position rather than by key names. Is there a way to deal with unstructured JSON data. @inquisitive_mind

Comment: Have you looked at ElephantBird? https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird